# How to refactor a lambda expression to a method reference?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, java-8, refactoring

My code looks like this:

```
class A {
    public void m() {
        Arrays.stream("a", "b")
            .map(x -> x + "!") // <-- lambda expression
            .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

I want to refactor it into:

```
class A {
    public void m() {
        Arrays.stream("a", "b")
            .map(this::t) // <-- method reference
            .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
    }

    public String t(String x) {
        return x + "!";
    }
}
```

How can I do this refactoring with IntelliJ?

Comment: Is it always that lambda? Can you just use search+replace? Or are you asking in general how to take a lambda which looks like that, make a method, and replace with the MR?

Comment: @AndyTurner I seek for a general answer, allowing to do this kind of refactoring. I have such a use case every now and then - and usually only have to refactor a single occurance at a time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Select the lambda, press Alt+Enter, click "Extract to Method Reference".

Comment: @slartidan Just tried it and it generates a `private static String apply(String x) {return x + "!";}`, which looks fine to me...

Comment: Is that item also available somewhere in the application menu?

Comment: Doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 2):

First, do the refactoring **extract method** on `x + "!"` code. Then use quick-fix **replace with method reference**.

Comment: This seems not to work for me. There is no such quick fix displayed at the generated `t()` call. Where should I see that quick fix?

Comment: @slartidan select the `x + "!"` and press ctrl-alt-M to extract method.

Comment: It results in `.map(t())` and a new method `private Function<String, String> t() {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. IntelliJ IDEA will warn you to use `Stream.of()` Instead of `Arrays#Stream`, because you are not supplying an `Array` but just two `String`s

After fixing that, just hit `alt`+`enter` standing in some place of `x -> x+ "!"` and press `Extract to Method reference`

But to be fair... if this tiny piece of code is the 'real deal' then please don't. It will make things less readable.

For this you are better of with something like:

```
System.out.println(String.join("!\n", new String[]{"a", "b"}));
```

or

```
Stream.of("a", "b").forEach(s -> System.out.printLn(s + "!"));
```

or even better:

```
for (String s : Arrays.asList("a", "b")) {
  System.out.println(s + "!");
}
```

Comment: Actually, it’s not a warning, but an *error* as `Arrays.stream("a", "b")` is not valid at all. In contrast, `String.join` allows varargs: `String.join("!\n", "a", "b")`. But it doesn’t produce the last `"!"`… By the way, you could also use `Arrays.asList("a","b").forEach(s->System.out.printLn(s+"!"));`, to name another variant.

Comment: It indeed is an error which IDEA will warn for with a warning message just after typing this line in the editor. It will give an error when compiling, but IDEA will warn you before that. It simply gives a `cannot resolve method...`

Comment: Interesting interaction between IDE and compiler. Eclipse and Netbeans don’t have that behavior, as they use an embedded compiler at that stage. On the other hand, only IDEA has the flexibility to change the compiler.